# Need help using goBack() in react native

Tags: javascript, react-native, webview, stack-navigator

I am having trouble with the back button in the stack navigator. I am getting an error saying undefined is not an object (evaluating '_this.props'). if it works it goes back to a different tab in the bottom stack navigator. Like if I click on book a session and then I go to home and click back it will take me to book a session no matter what. Please help.

This is what I have so far:

```
function HomeScreen({ navigation }) {
      
        return (
          <WebView
            source={{
              uri: 'https://www.stoodnt.com/'
            }}
            style={{ marginTop: -120 }}
          />
        );
         
}

const HomeStack = createStackNavigator();
function HomeStackScreen() {
 return (
   <HomeStack.Navigator>
    <HomeStack.Screen name="Home"
         component={HomeScreen}
         options={{
         headerLeft: () => (
           <HeaderBackButton
            onPress={() => this.props.navigation.goBack(null)}
            
           />
        ),
    }}
/>
   </HomeStack.Navigator>
  );
}
```

Bottom Navigator:

```
const Tab = createBottomTabNavigator();

export default function App() {

    return (
       <NavigationContainer>
         <Tab.Navigator
           screenOptions={({ route }) => ({
             tabBarIcon: ({ focused, color, size }) => {
               let iconName;

            if (route.name === 'Home') {
              iconName = focused
                ? 'ios-home'
                : 'ios-home';
            } else if (route.name === 'Book Session')  {
                iconName = focused ? 'ios-calendar' : 'ios-calendar';
            }
            else if (route.name === 'Blogs')  {
                iconName = focused ? 'ios-bookmark' : 'ios-bookmark';
            }
            else if (route.name === 'Online Courses') {
              iconName = focused ? 'ios-book' : 'ios-book';
            }
            else if (route.name === 'Classes') {
              iconName = focused ? 'ios-desktop' : 'ios-desktop';
            }

            return <Ionicons name={iconName} size={40} color={'orange'} />;

          },
        })}
            tabBarOptions={{
              activeTintColor: '#000000',
              inactiveTintColor: '#616161',
              labelStyle: {
                fontSize: 10,
              },
              style: {
                backgroundColor: '#F7F7F7',
              },
    }}

      >


            
          <Tab.Screen name="Home" component={HomeStackScreen} />
          <Tab.Screen name="Book Session" component={BookStackScreen} />
          <Tab.Screen name="Blogs" component={BlogStackScreen} />
          <Tab.Screen name="Online Courses" component={OnlineStackScreen} />
            <Tab.Screen name="Classes" component={ClassesStackScreen} />
        
        
            
        </Tab.Navigator>
    </NavigationContainer>
        
            
            


  );

}
```

[image]

Answer (score 0):

try the below code :

````
function HomeScreen(props) {
      
        return (
          <WebView
            source={{
              uri: 'https://www.stoodnt.com/'
            }}
            style={{ marginTop: -120 }}
          />
        );
         
}

const HomeStack = createStackNavigator();
function HomeStackScreen() {
 return (
   <HomeStack.Navigator>
    <HomeStack.Screen name="Home"
         component={HomeScreen}
        options={({ route, navigation }) => ({
         headerLeft: () => (
           <HeaderBackButton
            onPress={() => navigation.goBack(null)}
           />
        ),        
      })}

/>
   </HomeStack.Navigator>
  );
}```
````

Comment: If you find this answer helpfull then please upvote, accept the answer and close this issue. Thanks.

Comment: Hi! I have already tried that but I am still getting the same error. Please help.

Answer (score 0):

In functional components, you do not have access to "this". You should either pass navigation from the screen options or use useNavigation.

```
<HomeStack.Screen
   ...
   options={({navigation}) => (
      headerLeft: () => (
      // you can use navigation.goBack() here
      )
)}
```

or

```
    // this should be added right under function HomeStackScreen, 
    // right above the return and you will be able to use it in the screens
    const navigation = useNavigation()
```

Comment: Hi, I have added that but whenever I click "back" it brings me back to the tab navigator I clicked on before and not the page before. I forgot to say but I used a tab navigator to go to different screens. Please Help

Comment: @user14963385 First, try navigation.goBack() without the 'null', this should let react navigation handle going back to where it thinks you want to go. If this doesn't work and you know what page you want it to go back to, you could just navigate to that page instead.

Comment: I have tried that but it goes back to the tab I clicked on before in the bottom stack navigator. Please Help